# Get the closest previous element with a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've looked through several very similar questions but couldn't get this work. What I have is this `DOM` structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <input class="selected"/>

  <div class="dropdown-wrapper ae-hide">
    <div class="selectable">1</div>
    <div class="selectable">2</div>
    <div class="selectable">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when any of the `.selectable` is clicked I want to update the value of the input. The problem is that I can't find the correct selectors to do that. And this is dynamically created so I can have multiple `html` snippets like this one on my page that's why I'm using classes.

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dnj5hbxx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) is a sibling selector, so you need to be on the same level in the dom as the `input` element.

The first thing you will do is to use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the ancestor with class `dropdown-wrapper` (you could also use `parent()` in this case but closest is more flexible in case you change your dom structure). And on that result, you will call your `prev`

```
$('.selectable').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-wrapper').prev('.selected').val('hit');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed to do it myself with `parent()` but it's good to know that `closest()` is preferable in this situation.

Comment: @Leron with `closest()` the code would still be valid in case you change your markup to `<div class="dropdown-wrapper ae-hide"><div class="inner-decorator"><div class="selectable">1</div> ... </div></div>`. And it clearly explains to the reader that you don't look for the parent but for the `.dropdown-wrapper` ancestor which could be the parent but does not need to be the parent.

Comment: This answer works for that specific case, but not for the general problem described in the title. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find element is :

```
$( ".selectable" ).parent().parent().find('input').val('somevalue');


$( ".selected" ).each(function(index) {
      $(this).on("click", function(){
       This is multiple elements have their own function
       //var somevalue = $(this).attr('id'); 
       });
      });
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem, how to find the correct `input` element for the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

The next-to-last line in the JS code should be:

```
 $(this).parent().prev('.selected').val('hit');
```

(You want to address the previous *parent* from what I understood)

https://jsfiddle.net/o7s1xgdj/

Answer (score 0):

`.prev()` gives you only the immediatelly previous element and if you specify a filter selector like this `.prev('.selected')` it only returns the previous element IF it matches that selector. Meaning if the desired `.selected` element is not immediately before the current element, it will return nothing.

If you truly want to get the closest previous element with a class (even if it is not immediately before the current element) you have to approach it like this.

```
currentElem
.prevAll('.selected') // returns all previous elems with 'selected' class in reverse DOM order (the closest is the first)
.eq(0); // return the first element in the set - the closest one
```

Therefore in your case

```
$('.selectable').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-wrapper').prevAll('.selected').eq(0).val('hit');
});
```