# If child has an active class, add class to before anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list and that contains sub menus with title anchor tags. And I just need to add class to its title anchor tag if dropdown menu li has an active class. Please take a look at this screenshot.

[image]

I easily do this by adding unique class to anchor tag and find that and add class. But what if I have more sub menus with title tag? Then I have to repeat my jQuery script again and again.

So I tried this way doing.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery(".dropdown li").hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).closest("a").addClass("main-link");.
    }
  });
```

But it's not working. Is there any way to do this?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/wnqcemb5/14/)

Comment: `$(this)` isn't the `li` node. You probably want `$('.dropdown li').closest...` Edit: on second thought, you also want to loop over each of `$('.dropdown li')` and then check the conditional inside the loop. Or only select the active nodes in the first place: ` $('.dropdown li.active').closest('li').find('a').first().addClass('main-link');`

Comment: closest looks at parents, the anchor is not a parent.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the closest previous element with a class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658285/get-the-closest-previous-element-with-a-class-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest looks at parents, the anchor is not a parent. Plenty of ways to walk the tree

```js
$("li.active").parent().closest("li").find(">a").addClass("foo");

$("li:has(> ul > li.active)").find(">a").addClass("bar");
```

```css
.foo { background-color: yellow; }
.bar { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>A</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">X</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.closest()` finds the closest containing element that matches the selector. The `a` is not a container of the dropdown, it's the element *before* the dropdown. For that you need to use `.prev()`.

You also shouldn't be using `if` and `this`. `if` doesn't bind `this` to the elements where the condition succeeds. Just use a selector and DOM navigation from that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown:contains(li.active)").prev("a").addClass("main-link");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("li.active").parent().closest("li").find(">a").parent().addClass("active");
```

If child has an active class, add class to before anchor tag of parent